# MySQL Function to select records with words ordered the same as in Query?

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch records which contain a certain substring(set of words).

My problem is that MATCH() returns records which contain all words of substring scattered across in the fields. I don't want such records.

e.g.: 
If the substring is **"I like apples"** MATCH() returns records such as:

- like apples
- apples I like
- I like red apples

I want MySQL to return records with all the words in the substring together: Like fields with

- I Like apples and oranges
- I like apples, in fact I'm going to eat one now

How can I accomplish in MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, use 'LIKE' operator.

1> want to search the String 'I like apples' as starts with

use query as - `column_string LIKE 'I like apples%'`

2> want to search the String 'I like apples' as ends with

use query as - `column_string LIKE '%I like apples'`

3> want to search the String 'I like apples' any where in column

use query as - `column_string LIKE '%I like apples%'`

Comment: Would that be feasible for a large dataset? Isn't it slow to use LIKE for this kind of text comparisons? I read something about it long ago and probably got it all messed up

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the boolean mode for fulltext search.

Read more about it in the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Then you can simply enclose your search string with quotes `"` and you'll be fine.

Comment: `LIKE` should be faster. With no wildcard in front, i.e. `column LIKE 'whatever%'`, it can use indexes. Actually I'm a little embarassed why I didn't think of it :) Therefore +1 from me @Pradeep